# Grouping field in Kendo Grid by partial value of the field

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid with a field (Date) that contains values like:

```
Date
2018.03.05 10:33
2018.03.05 11:20
2018.04.11 14:30
```

Now I want to group based on the date, but I don't want to include the time  - or I would get all distinct groupings. I still want to display the time to the user, however.

I cannot find somewhere to modify the value before it's send to the grouping function. I could create an extra hidden field, populate it with the data, and somehow redirect the grouping to use that field, but this seems like an ugly solution, and I'm not even sure it's possible.

What can I do to archive the desired effect: 2 groups called 2018.03.05 and 2018.04.11?

Comment: It's kinda awkward but I'm afraid you're right, it is not possible without creating a *hidden* field. See [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/UsOWaGUh) and [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/UsOWaGUh/2).